# How to determine whether the substrate of an LED chip is p or n type using the bench equipment?

Tags: led

I was thinking that you could use an ammeter and see if there is positive or negative current passing through? Am I right or wrong on this?

Comment: Check the datasheet to find out which terminal is anode and which is cathode. Then, if the datasheet doesn't also tell you which is the substrate, look at it under magnification to figure out which terminal is connected to the substrate.

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons to know this, but I can't come up with any.  Would you mind to share them?

Comment: It was for a prelab. I was just trying to cross check with other people to see if I was right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a typical LED showing the internal construction (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode)):

[image]

The substrate is the side of the LED chip facing the "Anvil", in this case the cathode.  The cathode is always "N" type material.

Some LEDs are the reverse of the above diagram, with the substrate being "P" type, as you can see from this photo taken from a Cree [datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/CREE%20Power/C566C-RFx,GFx,BFx,AFx.pdf):

[image]

The long leads are the anodes, and you can see each 'anvil' through the tinted epoxy.

Answer (score 0):

The resistance is different in a diode depending on which direction the voltage is applied. Many multimeters also have a diode testing mode.

Comment: This tells you which pin is the anode and which is the cathode. But I don't see how it tells you which is the substrate.